# Conditionals for fish shell

Tags: shell, shell-script, fish

I am going through the fish shell tutorial and find that this simple if-else block does not work

```
if grep fish /etc/shells
            echo Found fish
else if grep bash /etc/shells
            echo Found bash
else
            echo Got nothing
end
```

Error message:

```
/usr/bin/fish
Found fish
fish: global root block
fish: Could not locate end of block. The 'end' command is missing, misspelled or
a ';' is missing.

       end - end a block of commands.
```

Answer (score 7):

Probably you have a very old (1.x) version of fish installed, which predates the else-if construct. What does `fish --version` output? Ideally you want 2.1.0.